# Using mailmerge to send one email to multiple recepients

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, mail-merge

I have a database with over 10,000 people in it and I want to send them a conference invitation to their emails. The problem is that the mail merge will send one email to each individual which will cause my sent box to be massive. Is there a way to send one email to multiple recipients and is it possible to specify whether I want to add the recipients to cc or bcc? Also, I'm wondering if there's a possibility to add an attachment as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried making a contact group of all of them and sending the invitation to only that contact group?

Comment: No, because the amount of emails is really massive. Unless there is a way to extract emails from an excel sheet, I'm not going to add them email by email.

Comment: How about [this] (https://www.uwsp.edu/infotech/Pages/Tutorials/Email/Import-Contact-Group-From-Excel.aspx) .

Comment: I don't see microsoft in the file type. I have followed all the steps 100% and made sure the new folder is "contact items"

Comment: https://s1.postimg.org/8fijgbaw33/2017-10-16_190250.jpg

Comment: [link] (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-contacts-from-an-Excel-spreadsheet-to-Outlook-f6483469-0684-4c30-82c5-c881930f54510 for this method of importing , you ll get the option of csv, try this out then follow the steps of the other link .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily avoid spamming your Sent Items. Just disable the "Save copies of messages in the Sent Items folder" in Outlook Options -> Mail -> Save messages. Then perform the MailMerge. After that, enable the option.